# What is a 32 x 8 Multiplier and Thumb Instruction Decoder in ARM7TDMI?

Tags: arm7, block-diagram

I'm a college student and only have a very basic knowledge of digital electronics and micro controllers. Recently I got interested in arm micro controllers and just stared to learn about them. While reading arm7tdmi technical reference manual I came across a block diagram of arm7tdmi in which I saw two blocks named "32x8 multiplier" and "Instruction pipeline, Read data register, Thumb instruction decoder".

[image: ARM7TDMI Block Diagram]

I have following questions/doubts:

1. What is the meaning of "32x8" in the 32x8 multiplier?
2. What is the function of the 32x8 multiplier?
3. What is the function of the Thumb instruction decoder and how does it work?
4. What is the data flow logic (through which buses will data come into the destination register) of load instruction?

Comment: Thumb is a small alternative instruction set that some ARM processors support.

Comment: Is this homework question? Have you tried to find the answers from the manual? What do you think the answer are?

Comment: No, it is not a homework problem. I'm learning on my own for my interest. Yes i tried to search in the manual and on the internet but i did not find any answer. I have no idea about these questions because I'm new to these things. And Yes I have some idea about 4th question but I'm not sure that it is correct. And also I know about thumb Instructions but don't know about thumb instruction decoder.

Comment: The ARM7TDMI manual actually has a detailed description of the 8x32bit multiplier, which requires careful scheduling and (if possible) choice of operand precision to get optimal performance. Take a look at the rest of the document.

Answer (score 3):

1. 32x8 means it can multiply a 32-bit number with an 8-bit number.
2. It multiplies numbers. It takes in two numbers and returns the result of a multiplication operation.
3. The CPU can be in ARM mode where it fetches ARM instructions for execution, or the CPU can be in Thumb mode where it fetches Thumb instructions for execution. The CPU can only work with ARM instruction set so the Thumb instructions need to be converted to ARM instructions for execution. The block decodes the fetched Thumb instructions into ARM instructions that can be executed.
4. There is only one input bus for anything, the RDATA bus.

Comment: To add clarity, the 32x8 multiplier works faster than doing the math in software.